# Newsletter checkbox within SignUpForm in django-allauth - Design considerations

Tags: django, django-allauth

I succeeded adding a checkbox in a custom SignupForm in django-allauth asking the user while signing up if they want to subscribe to newsletter.

I'm using Mailchimp for newsletter management and am calling the Mailchimp API whenever I want to subscribe a user / unsubscribe a user.

I'm wondering where is the correct place to hook the subscribe / unsubscribe API calls.

I first thought putting it on email_confirmed (I don't want to subscribe a user if his email hasn't been confirmed --> maybe it's fake and I'm gonna have bounces).

But then what happens when the user changes his primary email address?
Where would be a good place then to have the logic for subscribing / unsubscribing?

Can I have some custom logic in order to have a DRY hook or do I have to treat differently the signup and the change primary emails events to call my subscribe / unsubscribe API calls?

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this instruction will help you

> This is an instruction on how to add a "subscribe to mailchimp" on your Django website.
>
> Because most sites regularly use external connections nowadays, you don't want to have a high number of packages if it can be avoided. Django-requests makes swift work handling CURL and WGET calls in a better manner.
>
> This repo describes how to use Django-requests to make a CURL call to add a person to a mailchimp list.

https://github.com/arcee123/Django-mailchimp2.0-subscribe